# JQuery Delegate - Why are there two selectors?

Tags: jquery

I've just discovered delegate it looks really useful, but even after reading the documentation I'm still confused about something.

Previously I was binding all my events like this:

```
$("#myTextBox").on("input", control.Search);
```

Now I'm doing it according to the documentation like this:

```
$("#myDiv").delegate("#myTextBox", "input", control.Search);
```

Why does delegate use two selectors? Why not just:

```
$("#myTextBox").delegate("input", control.Search);
```

Comment: Did you even read the documentation ?

Comment: The first selector is the parent element to which the handler is actually assigned.  This element should be static in the life of the document.  The second selector is the filter for child elements for which the handler should be used.  These can dynamically come and go during the life of the document.  This works because events "bubble up" from children to parents.  So, for example, when you click on a button you also click on any div which contains that button, any parent element of that div, the body element, the html element, the document, the window...

Comment: Yes I did, I still dont understand why there's two selectors

Comment: @Owen if you had read the documentation then you should know that , .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method so you should not replace .on() with .delegate() but you should replace .delegate() with .on()

Comment: The second 'selector'  here is not a DOM selector but a reference to oninput event

Comment: Thank you for explaining it to me David!

Comment: And there are two selectors here. #myDiv and #myTextBox. I know what input means.

Answer (score 2):

The first selector is which element you are using as the "root" or "base" element, the second selector is the one you are attaching the event handler to.  It's purpose is to allow you to attach an event handler to a lower level element (lower level meaning an element further down the DOM), but have it handled up at a higher level.  Its usefulness is when you have dynamic DOM, like a TABLE where you are adding a bunch of rows that have buttons to remove the row or something.

You can also use the [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to perform the same deal.

Comment: I didn't realise you could do this with on(). Previously I'd been calling newElement.on() every time I added something to the page, hence the reason I was so happy to find delegate(). Thanks for actually understanding what I was asking and for the explanation.

Comment: No problems.  Just sharing my own "Aha!" moments when I can.

Answer (score 1):

From jQuery docs [.delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

> Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the
>   selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root
>   elements

.on only binds to events on elements which exist when [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is called:

> Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the
>   selected elements

You should also note that according to the docs:

> As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method

Comment: delegate is not deprecated

Answer (score 0):

JQuery's documentation explains it well: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/
Also, delegating is deprecated since JQuery 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

[.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) is used to register event handlers using event delegation...

When a normal event registration is used it registers handlers to only those elements which are present in the dom at the time of execution of the registration code. When we may have to deal with dynamically added elements this approach may not be feasible.

In event delegation model the handler is registered to a ancestor element which will be present when the page is loaded with the a selector to filter out the source element. This makes use of event propagation - events happening in an element is propagated to all the ancestor elements(there are few exceptions like focus event). So an event happening in an element gets propagated to the ancestor element in one of them the handler is registered then the events source element(event.target) and its ancestors is matched against the selector passed as the second parameter, if it is satisfied then the handler is executed.
http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

So in case of `delegate()`, the event handler is added to the set of elements on which the `delegate()` method is called, and when the `input` event bubbles from its decedents to the element when the selector is used to determine whether to execute the handler for the event.